# Toshiba Satellite C655 Windows 7

Tags: windows-error-reporting

My laptop fell on the floor while on and now reads "A disk read error occurred Press Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart. How can I fix this without spending a bunch of money on fix-it software?

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't fix that with software.
At minimum the SATA cable has come loose. At worst, it suffered a head crash & the hard drive is destroyed.

Depending on your technical ability, your next step is to dismantle to test, or take it to a repair shop.